# Weblogic targeted runtime error - target runtime is not defined error

Tags: javascript, java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, weblogic

[Please click the Image for Eclipse weblogic error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mqnjK.png)

I have targeted runtime set and still I find this error. Any solutions to this?

Please help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Did you check the link to the image? I have specified the error givrn there and also shown the configurstion asked is done. And asking for further resolutions